# Receiving part of data with recv(), is that possible?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, recv

I'm using non-blocking sockets with winsock and I wonder that if I can partially receive data ?

My packet contains a "length" WORD and I must first read it then read whole packet according to the "length".

Actually this question is like "how does recv() work and end ?", Can i use recv() until I got all the data ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the type of the socket. If it's a datagram socket, `recv` will read exactly one entire datagram. If it's a TCP socket:

- `recv` will read at least one byte before returning
- `recv` can read more than one complete `message`

If you're using TCP, you'll probably want to do something like this:

- Read at least the bytes comprising the length
- Read `length` bytes
- You now have a complete message
- Rinse, repeat

You could start with the [`readn` function](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169505&seqNum=9).

Comment: is it a relative operation ? i mean i have packet with char x,y,z; 
first i read 1 byte, so i got x, will i get x again if i read 1 byte or y ?

Answer (score 2):

For TCP socket: You can use recv in a loop until you have got enough bytes.
Note that recv may return less bytes than you requested. In that case just keep calling until you have the whole message.